# representations of Complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Lets say that we have the complex function $w= \sqrt{(4-z)(z+2i)(z-2i)}$ .We want to rewrite this as complex exponentials... So we write $z+2i= r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$,
$z-2i=r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$, but does $4-z= - r_3e^{i\theta_3}$, that is, is the minus sign here for $4-z$ necessary????

Comment: Time to learn some MathJax...

Comment: No, the minus sign is not necessary there, it can be *hidden* in $e^{i\theta_3}$ (note that $-1=e^{i\pi}$).